# Creating vector with one unknown using a function

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, math, scipy

I have a problem that I cannot get my head around although there must be a simple way to do so. Basically, I have this function:

```
Pr(d) = Pr(d_0) -10*n*lodg(d/d_0)
```

where we can ignore (for now) the `Pr(d)` term. Now, I want to pass the follwing dataframe:

```
                          d  
0                        200      
1                        600      
2                        800      
3                       1000
```

with `d_0` constant. I sould actually pass it as an array using `df_matrix = df.to_numpy()`.

What I want is to create a function

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sympy import symbols, solve
from scipy.optimize import fsolve
import math

def recieved_power(pr_d0,d_0, x):
    pr_d0 -10*n*math.log(d/d_0)
```

that will return a vector with the variable `n` (unknown). It should return:

```
-3.0102999566398116*n
-7.781512503836435*n
-9.030899869919434*n
-10.0*n
```

Is that possible. I cannot just multiply by `n` afterwards because there might be new factors in a later stage of the work.

Thanks for any insight.

Comment: Do you want to return a lambda function of variable *n* with different parameters?

Comment: If the resulting vector useful for later calculations, then it might be an alternative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you change

```
def recieved_power(pr_d0,d_0, x):
    pr_d0 -10*n*math.log(d/d_0)
```

into

```
def recieved_power(pr_d0,d,d_0):
    return lambda n: [ pr_d0 -10*n*math.log(single_d/d_0) for single_d in d]
```

For example, the following code snippet takes in the parameters pr_d0, d and d0 and returns a function which takes in n and outputs a list of numbers, each of which representing a single **pr_d0 -10*n*math.log(d/d_0)** value

```
import math

d=[200,600,800,1000]

def recieved_power(pr_d0,d,d_0):
    return lambda n: [ pr_d0 -10*n*math.log(single_d/d_0) for single_d in d]   

func_list=recieved_power(0,d,d_0=1)

print(func_list(3))
```

Comment: Thank you! So, in other words, it isn't possible to make the output contain an unknown. RIght?

Comment: Happy to help. Actually, you can swap the **lambda** and list comprehension order, but since Python copies references alongside values, this way leads to messy coding. Except these two, I don't know any better solution.